# Wordpress site dont send emails to google workspace email accounts

Tags: wordpress, email, google-workspace, wpforms, wp-mail

I have a site with wordpress, which sends emails via wpforms and wpmail smtp. It works fine except when the recipient is a Google Workspace account.

I get an error 500, The user does not exist.

In cPanel I checked the dkim, dmarc and spf records and they are correct. If I check them with an online service, it tells me that they are fine.

Has any of you experienced something similar?

The site is an online store, I need to send proof of purchase emails to the user, but if his Google Workspace account does not reach the emails.